# SP2013 : Create a list item inside a folder

Tags: 2013

How to create a list item inside a folders of custom sharepoint list using JSOM ?

Below code is not working
http://www.sharepointcolumn.com/create-list-item-in-folders-using-client-object-model/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `SP.ListItemCreationInformation.set_folderUrl` method ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj245252.aspx)).

And here is a simple example:

```
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Custom');

var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
// need to specify full path after site domain , ex: 
// "/sites/DMS/Lists/Custom/Folder" 
itemCreateInfo.set_folderUrl('/sites/DMS/Lists/Custom/Folder');

var listItem = list.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
listItem.set_item('Title', 'Hello!');
listItem.update();

clientContext.load(listItem);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function (sender, arges) {
    alert('Added');
}, function (sender, arges) {
    alert(arges.get_message());
});
```

This will create a new list item under "Folder" in "Custom" list.